# eg - Component rerenders after input value is changed ? How to correct it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Actually , I am fecthing an object by clicking on submit Click button and pushing that object in the array names biodata and sorting the array acc to the no of followers of the object (in useeffect())
The problem is it is not rendering the sorted array until i make some changes in the input box
import React from 'react'
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'

```
import axios from 'axios';
function Search(){

const [searchkeyword,inputchange] = useState("");
const [biodata,setbiodata] =useState([]);

   const load=(e)=>{
       axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${searchkeyword}`).
       then((response)=>setbiodata((biodata)=>[...biodata,response.data])).catch((err)=>console.log(err.message))
       e.preventDefault();
    }
   function compare( a, b ) {
    if ( a.followers > b.followers ){
      return -1;
    }
    if ( a.followers < b.followers ){
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
   useEffect(()=>{
       
       document.getElementById("myform").reset()
       biodata.sort(compare);
       setbiodata(biodata)
       console.log("cahnge")
       
   },[biodata])

    return(
        <div>
         <form id="myform">
        <input type="text" id="a" onChange={(e)=>{inputchange(e.target.value)}} ></input>
        <button type="submit" onClick={load}>Click</button>
        </form>
        { biodata.length>0  &&
             biodata.map((e)=>{
                 return(
                     <div key={e.id}> 
                         <p>{e.login}</p>
                         <p>{e.followers}</p>
                        </div>

                 );
             })
        }
        </div>
    );
}


export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it does render the sorted array, is it actually sorted? I cant test it right now but you might want to change your useEffect to this:

```
document.getElementById("myform").reset()
   const sortedBioData = biodata.sort(compare);
   setbiodata(sortedBioData)
   console.log("cahnge")
```

Note that changing the biodata state in the useEffect might cause an infinate state loop

Comment: no effect on making this change . Actually it is sorting the array but not rerendering on the ui until i make some changes in input